# R - Update column by looping through it

Tags: r, string, loops

I want to update a column value in such a way that only the part of a string after the last '.' is stored. I wrote a code that does this but it only works when it's given one input. How do I loop through all the rows of my dataframe?

One value of a row looks for example like this. I only want to store the last part ".gif"

```
GET /./enviro/gif/emcilogo.gif
```

I wrote the following code that succesfully does this.

```
tail(c(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(sapply(strsplit("GET /./enviro/gif/emcilogo.gif", "\\s+"), `[`, 2)),"\\."))), n=1)
```

Output:

```
"gif"
```

However, I am using the string "GET /./enviro/gif/emcilogo.gif" as input. As soon as I change this to the column of my dataframe "df$request" I receive the error.

```
Error in strsplit(epa.df$request) : 
  argument "split" is missing, with no default
```

I tried writing a function that one-by-one loops through my column values and updates them. However, I cant seem to get this working.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this help: `x <- "GET /./enviro/gif/emcilogo.gif"; basename(chartr(".", "/", x))` ?

Comment: `gsub(pattern = ".*\\.", replacement = "", s)`, where s is the string or even a data frame column